# Differential DAC filter capacitor options

Tags: filter, differential, dac, low-pass

The standard output filter for a DAC with a differential voltage output looks this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXI98J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, some DACs have this filter configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flCj8S.png)</sup>

Simulation shows that both circuits work and provide 2nd order filtering. My question is what is the difference between the two, are they always interchangeable, and what are possible pros and cons of the second circuit?

Comment: Bkxp if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is what is the difference between the two*

If the signal the DAC that the DAC produces is truly differential then the mid-point AC voltage of the two capacitors (C1 and C3 in your first diagram) will be zero and, can connect to 0 volts or, be left open-circuit. If left open-circuit then you end up with the same circuit as shown in your 2nd image.

> *are they always interchangeable*

"Always" is such a contentious word so, without considering every circuit possibility (including using a different input sources) the answer has to be no.

> *what are possible pros and cons of the second circuit?*

I prefer the first circuit because it unambiguously offers independent filtering for each channel.

Answer (score 0):

Are they interchangeable?

No. They behave similarly in the simulator, that is, they provide essentially the same performance to wanted signals. However, they behave differently to unwanted signals.

Grounding the C1/3 connection in the first circuit means that it has more attenuation to common-mode signals. A DAC might produce logic signal feedthrough, or power supply ripple, in common-mode on its analogue outputs. However, if the following circuit demands good differential signal balance, a tolerance difference between C1 and C3 might unbalance the signal in the way that the second circuit might not.

Which one is 'better' depends on which imperfections of your DAC, and the following circuitry, the network is intended to improve.